# regexp find and replace: bash variables inside sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to remove this sequence when present at the beginning of the line:

ATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTGACCAATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG followed by at least 3 A characters.

Both, sequence and multiple A should be removed and the rest of the file should be preserved.

My input files look like this:

```
@M00946:3:000000000-A2WF2:1:1101:18115:1962 1:N:0:2
GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTGACCAATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTGAAAAAAAAAACATTTTCTTTCTTACTTCGTTCACTTTCCACTTCTTTCTCCCTATCTTCCCCCTTCTGTCTGCCCCAGCTGTCTATCCCACTTATTGTCTCCCCCCACTGCCCCACACTCCTACCTTCTTCATCTTCACCTAACACCTCCCGCTCCCTCCTTATCGTCTCTTATCCTTTCCTTGTTCC
+
????????DDDDDDDDGGGGGGHHIIIIHHHIIIIFHIIIH/CGFHHIIIIHEDHHIIIIHI=5EEGFEHHEC+5,,4@,@,,....--..+77,,.6..6.....7.4..7.76=..-5.>.4-)134-.5....-3*))0***1*********10*0**01*1*)''..0***.)0'))*****00*11******01***0****0*)**0)'''...*0)0*11********1****1*0********
@M00946:3:000000000-A2WF2:1:1101:19888:2900 1:N:0:2
GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTGACCAATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTGAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAATACCGTTCCAATATCTTTTTGTTTCATGTCTAATAAC
+
<<??????BB?BBBBBCAFFFCFHF;>EFCDFGFFHFBGHCA=FHA>EFGEE7CF>F?FFHB=?EEGF>>DH5<)++,++,4,,4+=:,,,,5,,,,,,,,),33?,3,3,3,,,,33
```

I was trying to use script replace.sh which looks like this

```
file=$1;
adapter_sequence=$2;
sed -r "s/${adapter_sequence}A{3}//" $file
```

from the command line:

./replace.sh file.fastq GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTGACCAATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG

It did not work. Any help in any script language will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your have `$1`, `$2` reversed. Have it like this:

```
adapter_sequence=$2
sed "s/$adapter_sequence//" $1
```

> In the ideal case I would like to remove all adapter sequences
>   starting at the beginning of line followed by at least three A
>   letters,

Try this sed:

```
sed -r "s/^${adapter_sequence}A{3,}//" file
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more readable, sorry for confusion,